# Record a video from browser in iOS, Mac OS, Windows and Android

Tags: safari, webrtc, video-capture, mediarecorder, recordrtc

I have to record a video from browser. This has to work on all the browsers. Things that I have tried -

1. Web RTC
2. Record RTC
3. VideoJS-Record

The problem with each one of this is that it internally calls MediaRecorder API.
MediaRecorder is not supported in Safari.

Any other way out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the MediaRecorder API *is* supported in Safari as an "experimental feature".

You can enable the MediaRecorder API by following these steps:

1. Go to your Safari browser.
2. At the top, go to the develop tab.
3. Go to **Experimental Features**.
4. Click on MediaRecorder.
5. Reload the page.

The MediaRecorder API should now be enabled.